# Sending multiple records to Web API through Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api2

We are implementing a Investment Declaration module in mobile app. The Ionic developer has developed the investment declaration page which even has an option of multiple document adding. But now how will he send me(to API) the multiple details.

I have added the image of investment declaration form page for better understanding.

[Investment Declaration Form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ3n6.png)

This image is of our web application project. In web Application we are doing something like this:

```
Protected Sub btnApplyInvestment_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnApplyInvestment.Click

    Try
        Dim mEmpInvestmentDeclare As EmpInvestmentDeclare = ViewState("EmpInvestmentDeclare")
        With mEmpInvestmentDeclare
            .PayCareYearId = ViewState("yearId")
        End With
        Dim mEmpInvestmentDeclareDetails As EmpInvestmentDeclareDetails = mEmpInvestmentDeclare.EmpInvestmentDeclareDetails
        Dim mEmpInvestmentDeclareDetail As EmpInvestmentDeclareDetail = Nothing

        For Each rowHead As GridViewRow In gridDeclaredHead.Rows
            Dim gridInvestment As GridView = Nothing
            With rowHead
                gridInvestment = .FindControl("gridInvestment")
                If Not gridInvestment Is Nothing Then
                    Dim fieldIdHidden As HiddenField = Nothing
                    Dim txtAmount As TextBox = Nothing

                    For Each row As GridViewRow In gridInvestment.Rows
                        With row
                            fieldIdHidden = .FindControl("fieldIdHidden")
                            txtAmount = .FindControl("txtAmount")

                            If fieldIdHidden.Value = 26 Then
                                Dim m = 12
                            End If
                            If Not fieldIdHidden Is Nothing AndAlso Not txtAmount.Text.Length = 0 Then
                                'If CInt(txtAmount.Text) > 0 Then
                                mEmpInvestmentDeclareDetail = mEmpInvestmentDeclareDetails.GetEmpInvestmentDeclareDetailById(fieldIdHidden.Value)
                                With mEmpInvestmentDeclareDetail
                                    .DeclaredAmount = Val(txtAmount.Text)
                                    .PayCareYearId = ViewState("yearId")
                                    .ApplyEdit()
                                End With
                                'End If
                            End If
                        End With
                    Next

                End If
            End With
        Next

        Dim temp As EmpInvestmentDeclare = mEmpInvestmentDeclare.Clone
        mEmpInvestmentDeclare = mEmpInvestmentDeclare.Save()
```

Please can someone suggest something similar to this. Here we can simply loop through our grid and make a collection of the details which we later on save it.

But in Ionic we don't have a grid nor I can loop it. I am just stuck with this module.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, you should use FormGroup.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Todo</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
      </ion-item>
      <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!todo.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class FormsPage {
  private todo : FormGroup;

  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
    this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
    });
  }
  logForm(){
    console.log(this.todo.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand a bit of it. Could you please explain this to me, like how and were to implement this?